# Activity Indicator is not displaying in middile - XamarinForms WinPhone81

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm experiencing a strange behaviour of ActivityIndicator in my XamarinForms project. The indicator loads up perfectly in WinPhone81 but not in the middle of the layout for the first time, but it works perfectly from the second time to infinity. Below is the code I used:

In XAML:

```
<StackLayout x:Name="blueBar" Padding ="0,0,0,0" Orientation ="Vertical"
HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
</StackLayout>
```

In CS:

```
ActivityIndicator loading = new ActivityIndicator();

    blueBar.Children.Add(loading);
    loading.IsRunning = true;
    //some functions
    blueBar.Children.Remove(loading);
```

Does any knows why its behaving like this ?!

Any suggestions/guide/help will be appreciated..!!

Thanks in advance.

```
Note: The ActivityIndicator works well and fine in Droid & iOS projects.
```

Output: as I'm experiencing

1.First time execution of the page:

[image]

2.Second time execution of the same page:

[image]

Output: as per -Chandresh Khambhayata

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for helping me out guys...

I Finally figured out an answer for my question...

Here is the working code of mine (on all the three platforms).

XAML :

```
<StackLayout x:Name="blueBar" Padding="0,0,0,0" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
   <ActivityIndicator x:Name="loading" IsRunning="true"></ActivityIndicator>
</StackLayout>
```

CS :

```
somebtn.Clicked += async(sender,e) => {

    loading.IsVisible = true;

    //some await functions like api call or something

    loading.IsVisible = false;
}
```

The actual problem is., the Indicator is not allocated by InitializeComponent() before., so when I click any of the button for the first time., Indicator displays to the left of the layout.

But., now the Indicator is initialized by InitializeComponent()., and so the indicator is displaying in the middle for the first click itself...

```
Note : This problem only occured on windowsphone only not on ios and android projects.
       Now the updated code works well and good on all the three platforms.
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you need to put your `StackLayout` inside a `AbsoluteLayout` first in order for you to adjust the `ActivityIndicator` to the middle.

This should [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36177128/how-to-show-activityindicator-in-the-middle-of-the-screen) help you.

Haven't tried this yet, but it looks like you need to do a lot of stuff to achieve it.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the quick response man.. But It works fine for Droid and iOS... And Btw the link you shared is a dead link... (I mean the link you shared is not working, it is broken)

Comment: Probably, it's because of the `https`, someone edited it already. Check it out again :)

Comment: That link was helpful man., but i dont want to overlay my screen with that indicator... It is simple just add indicator to a layout and remove it after some time.. Its that simple...

Answer (score 0):

if you want to display ActivityIndicator in center of the screen then you most have to apply `HorizontalOptions="Center"` and `VerticalOptions="Center"`

I am using the below XML code and it's working perfect for me.

```
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
    <ActivityIndicator Color="White" HorizontalOptions="Center"  VerticalOptions="Center" />
    <Label Grid.Row="1" x:Name="LabelLoading" HorizontalOptions="Center" TextColor="White" Text="Loading..." FontFamily="Droid Sans Mono" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
</StackLayout>
```

Here is programmatically setting activity indicator.

```
ActivityIndicator activityIndecator = new ActivityIndicator();
activityIndecator.Color = Color.White;
activityIndecator.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;
activityIndecator.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;
blueBar.Children.Remove(activityIndecator);
```

Thank You.

Comment: This should work. But I'm not really sure, when this is done programmatically.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time guys... But no luck for me... I'll add the output for the above code as image in my question. Please do take a look...

Comment: @Senthamizh do you want to use the Indicator overlaying on the screen?

Comment: No absolutely not... @ChandreshKhambhayata I just wanna add it in that layout for a while and remove after performing some functions... I have updated my question with images..

Comment: can you please explain your question? I am assuming that we are not on same page.

Comment: Sure.. I have multiple buttons in that page., each button will load content through api's., and while loading the contents I want to display the indicator inside that layout.. Everything is working fine in Droid, iOS, and WinPhone81. But the only problem in windows is., it is not displaying in the middle for the first click(of any button)., from the second click to 'n' clicks indicator works well and fine...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134451/discussion-between-senthamizh-and-chandresh-khambhayata).